# How to programatically force Windows to update a file's reported on-disk size, while the file is being written?

Tags: c, file, winapi, filesize

I've got a program that opens an ASCII log file and writes lines of text to the end of it whenever events occur.  The timing of the events is unpredictable; they may happen many times per second, or they may only happen once every few hours.

This all works fine; the problem comes when I want to see what the current size of the log file is, while the program is running.  Under Windows, if I enter `dir` into a DOS shell, the log file's size shows up as 0 bytes, until such time as my program closes the log file.  (Interestingly, if I do a `dir my_file_name.log`, the file's size updates, but just a plain `dir` does not update the file size)

This is less useful than I would like; however according to [this  question/answer on SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/727883/why-some-write-in-progress-files-report-0-byte-but-shrinking-drives-free-space), that behavior is a "feature" of the Windows OS.  The answer even gives a hack work-around to force the file-size figure to update (by entering `type my_file_name.log > nul` into the DOS box).

My question is, is there some programmatic way to force that same update from within my program?  I'd like to be able to at least occasionally force the correct size to be shown, without having to tell the user to manually perform a work-around step.

I tried simulating the behavior of `type` from within my program, by doing a separate call to `fopen()` and `fclose()` on my log file's filepath, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

I also tried forcing the issue by calling `fclose()` on my log file's file-handle, and then re-opening the file in append-mode immediately afterwards (via `fopen()` again), but for some reason the `fopen()` call failed.  (I don't really want to do this anyway, for precisely the reason that re-opening the file might fail, leaving my program in an undesirable state)

See toy example program below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int args, char ** argv)
{
   FILE * fpOut = fopen("my_log_file.txt", "w");
   if (fpOut)
   {
      for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
      {
         fprintf(fpOut, "Event %i occurred\n", i);
         fflush(fpOut);

         Sleep(1000);

         // is there something I could call here to make the file's new size visible to the world?
      }
      fclose(fpOut);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have to admit I'd love to know an actual answer. I've taken to adjusting the reader where possible to ask for it the right way so it doesn't get the cached value. (Hint: cygwin's ls is not fooled.)

Comment: If you have the file open can't you just use `ftell`?

Comment: @JonathanPotter - what sense in ftell ?

Comment: i think best what you can do here - call `GetFileAttributesW`

Answer (score 0):

you can do exactly what linked port suggested: open and close it

> One can use anything that opens the file (creating a separate SFT entry) and closes it again. It can be something as simple as the type command running in another console/session: `type file > nul`

try something like that:

```
if ((i % 10) == 0) {
    FILE* tmp = fopen("my_log_file.txt", "r");
    if (tmp) fclose(tmp);
}
```

note: it opens new description and closes it, original write one is unaffected

Comment: enouth call `ZwQueryAttributesFile`

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I tried the fopen()/fclose() trick, and it doesn't seem to work.... fopen() just returns NULL and the file size doesn't change.

Comment: @RbMm calling `GetFileAttributesA("my_log_file.txt");` seems to do the trick, thanks!

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I tested it on windows 10, msvc - works like charm, if you're getting null from fopen then check errno to find out actual problem

Comment: @IłyaBursov I checked errno, it gets set to 13/permission denied

Comment: *"you can do exactly what linked port suggested: open and close it"* - That's not what the Super User Q&A suggests. It explicitly explains that the directory entry gets updated once **all** handles to the file get closed. Randomly creating a new file handle and closing it doesn't establish this condition.

Comment: @IInspectable you misread it, opening file for reading creates new SFT and only one handle to it, this is why size is flushed when you close it

Comment: @IłyaBursov you are correct. open and close file done the task. but we can fail open file for read access,  due share violation (depend how is file was open for writting)) the best - query file attributes. it not require close call, ask for read attributes only access, which not lead to share violation

Comment: @RbMm right, attributes is the better option